# Scripting in Grafana

Tags: grafana

I am a beginner in Grafana and I am trying to go through all the tutorial and documentation from Grafana.net, however, I am having trouble learning how to do scripted dashboard on Grafana, there is a documentation page on the site but it is very brief and I do not know how to proceed. Could anyone share with me a useful site for learning how to build scripted Dashboard on Grafana (especially using InfluxDB as the DB server).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my understanding :
  In the folder grafana install folder under public/dashboards/ there is a file named scripted.js

you have to modify **scripted.js** file.

**In Brief :**

First you need to install GRAFANA (centos or ubuntu anything)
 then Configure the grafana Example

path : /etc/yum.repos.d/grafana.repo

**configuration and installation link :**

http://docs.grafana.org/installation/rpm/

now you can check your grafana related file using grep or find commands and check required path.

then

In the folder grafana install folder under public/dashboards/ there is a file named scripted.js

you have to modify scripted.js file.

You can take help of below given site :

https://github.com/grafana/grafana/blob/master/docs/sources/reference/scripting.md